# how to fix this error "External ID not found in the system: sales_team.menu_sales"

Tags: odoo-12

i want to add new menuitem under management menu in accounting module, so what is the wrong with mine??
this is my xml file

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="cashflow_form_view">
        <field name="name">cash.flow.forecast</field>
        <field name="model">cashflow.forecast</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Cash Flow Forecast">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="from_date"/>
                        <field name="to_date"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_cashflow_forecast">
        <field name="name">Cash Flow Forecast</field>
        <field name="res_model">cashflow.forecast</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="menu_cashflow_forecast" name="Cash Flow Forecast" sequence="3"
              action="action_cashflow_forecast" parent="menu_finance_entries_management"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any external_id(menu_finance_entries_management in your case) from another module then you have to specify module name for that id replace menu_finance_entries_management with account.menu_finance_entries_management.

Comment: <menuitem id="menu_cashflow_forecast" name="Cash Flow Forecast" sequence="3" action="action_cashflow_forecast" parent="account.menu_finance_entries_management"/>

Comment: thanks akshay i tried it before .. but also doesn't work

Comment: no , without errors but the menuitem doesn't appear

Comment: id                      ,name                    ,model_id:id            ,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_cashflow_forecast,access.cashflow.forecast,model_cashflow_forecast,           ,1        ,1         ,1          ,1

Comment: but the group doesn't appear in the access rights tab of cashflow.forecast model

Comment: which group doesn't appear?

Comment: this one .. access_cashflow_forecast

Comment: check in access rights your rule is present there or not if not found either you forgot to put this file in your manifest.